# How can I wipe my Chromebook without the powerwash button?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, wipe, factory-defaults

I have a Chromebook, and ideally, I'd like to restore it to it's factory state, without any owners, any user accounts, or any data whatsoever. There's only one problem.

I have no access to the powerwash button.

Is there a way to completely wipe and restore my Chromebook to it's factory state?

---

To clarify, I've already tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>, and various other methods.

Comment: This may help: http://www.howtogeek.com/190645/how-to-factory-reset-a-chromebook-even-if-it-wont-boot/

Comment: Google search returns to do: Sign out of your Chromebook. When the sign-in screen appears, press and hold Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R (*NO* Power button). When the dialog for Powerwash opens, press and hold Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R again. Click Revert, then follow the instructions that appear.

Comment: @Ethan Bierlein Do you mean your model of Chromebook has a physical powerwash button or can you not navigate to the settings  > powerwash?